# how do i make a form that when clicked submit to node.js express server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried but it doesn't work any idea?

this is my code:

```
res.get("/signin", function(req, res) {
     res.render("signin")
     console.log(req.body)
}
```

when it shows `undefined` and if I use body-parser it doesn't log when submitted instead it logs `{}`  to the console

Comment: Use `console.log(req.body)` (without quotes).

Comment: oh yeah i accidentally added in the code ignore it

Comment: edit the code in the question if you're still having the problem

Comment: changed the code

Comment: can you show the code where you use body parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking — there are some exceptions but not when the client is a browser — you will not get a request body on a GET request.

If you are submitting a `<form>` then you need to make a POST request to get a body.

- Set the `method` attribute of the `<form>`
- Configure express with a `.post()` route and not a `.get()` route.